# Order rules execution without using declare salience

Tags: clips, fuzzy-logic

Well thats the question, imagine i have 2 rules. The second rule depends on the first rule.
For example:

```
 (deftemplate person 
(slot name (type STRING))
(slot age (type STRING))
)

(deffacts start
 (person(name "Mike")(age "20"))
 (person(name "Laura")(age "22"))
 (person(name "Dean")(age "22"))
 (person(name "Charlie")(age "22"))
 )

 (defrule filterage
 (person (name ?n)(age ?a))
 (test (eq ?a "22"))
 =>
 (assert (is-equal-to-22 ?n))
 )

 (defrule creategroup
 (is-equal-to-22 ?c)
 =>
 (assert (is-in-22-years-old-group ?c))
 )
```

And as expected the second rule fires any time it has something from rule 1.

[image]

So, how can i make the second rule wait till all persons are created, without using *declare salience*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         CLIPS (6.31 2/3/18)
CLIPS> (defmodule MAIN (export ?ALL))
CLIPS> (defmodule FILTER (import MAIN ?ALL))
CLIPS> (defmodule CREATE (import MAIN ?ALL))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate MAIN::av ; attribute value
  (slot a)
  (slot v))
CLIPS>   
(deftemplate MAIN::person 
  (slot name)
  (slot age))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts MAIN::start
  (person (name "Mike") (age 20))
  (person (name "Laura") (age 22))
  (person (name "Dean") (age 22))
  (person (name "Charlie") (age 22)))
CLIPS>   
(defrule MAIN::start
  =>
  (focus FILTER CREATE))
CLIPS> 
(defrule FILTER::filterage
  (person (name ?n) (age 22))
  =>
  (assert (av (a is-equal-to-22) (v ?n))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule CREATE::creategroup
  (av (a is-equal-to-22) (v ?c))
  =>
  (assert (av (a is-in-22-years-old-group) (v ?c))))
CLIPS> (watch rules)
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)  
FIRE    1 start: *
FIRE    2 filterage: f-4
FIRE    3 filterage: f-3
FIRE    4 filterage: f-2
FIRE    5 creategroup: f-7
FIRE    6 creategroup: f-6
FIRE    7 creategroup: f-5
CLIPS>
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit about what `defmodules` are used for? and what `focus defmodule` is used for? I searched it on the last Clips 6.40 documentation but i couldn't find it. Also, i'm forced to use FuzzyClips 6.10d, so the question would be if this would work on my FuzzyClips version. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Section 10 of the Basic Programming Guide describes defmodule which will work with FuzzyCLIPS 6.1.